# Markdown formatter that converts inline links to reference-style links

Tags: command-line, markdown, text-processing, utility, formatter

I would like to find a CLI utility that replaces the inline links of a markdown file to reference-style links, a la [this example](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#an-example-putting-the-parts-together).

On [this website](https://raymii.org/s/articles/Convert_markdown_inline_links_to_reference_style_links_with_Pandoc.html), I found a pandoc command that does something similar:

```
pandoc --from markdown --to markdown --reference-links --output outputfile.md inputfile.md
```

However, it's not a perfect solution. Running it on my jekyll blog posts deletes their [YAML front matter block](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/). The command also uses the link text for the reference, but I would prefer the number (like in the example).

Bonus if it can wrap the converted text afterwards.